# Hardening of nsswitch.conf and sysctl.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardening

I read somewhere (I forgot where) that the following should be set if I want to harden my linux, which is Ubuntu 18.04 in my case.

However, using these values somehow caused a 504 Gateway Time-out for my nginx, which is used as a reverse proxy for my asp.net core app.

I have no background in linux and all I did is copy paste.  So, I have no idea what setting these values even mean.

Is there any incorrect value(s) that I am setting wrong?

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:files
shadow:files
group:files
hosts:dns files
bootparams:files
ethers:files
netmasks:files
networks:files
protocols:files
rpc:files
services:files
automount:files
aliases:files
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
kernel.sysrq=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NSSWITCH.CONF**
All of these settings are `files`, which means everything is stored on the local computer.
Ex: `passwd:files` -- all login accounts are stored in /etc/passwd. There is no external user authentication (On Windows, this might be AD), LDAP, Kerberos, etc.
If this is what you expect, then those settings are correct.
They are probably not causing you gateway issue.


**sysctl.conf**
The rp_filter settings are most likely causing your problem. `rp_filter` means Reverse Path Filtering. A setting of `1` disable rp_filtering.

> which is used as a reverse proxy for my asp.net core app.

Set this value to 0 and try again.
0 = Allow All
1 = Disallow All
2 = Only allow from Networks I know (i.e. prevent "outside" networks, such as the internet). This may not be supported on all OS'
[What is RP Filtering](https://www.slashroot.in/linux-kernel-rpfilter-settings-reverse-path-filtering)
This article shows some echo commands. These are temporary changes that will work until you restart the machine. This way, you can test new settings without having to reboot all the time. Once you find settings that work, you can put them in sysctl.conf.

ip_forwarding may also be causing you problems. Try resetting that value also.

Here is some information on [sysctl.conf](https://networkengineer.me/2015/06/17/sysctl-etcsysctl-conf/)

if you are not using ipv6, you can leave those settings.

Remember that hardening a system usually breaks it. you need to adjust the settings for the use of the computer. As is the case here, RP Filtering has been disabled when, in reality, THIS computer needs it on.